# How to add a cell to a tableView withought reloading all data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I add a cell (custom) to a tableView? I have tried the following:

```
  @IBAction func AddCommentButton(_ sender: Any) {
        addComment() {
             //1)
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [arrayOfComments.count].indices, with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
               //2)
//            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)) as! commentTableViewCell
//            addTemporaryComment(cell: cell)
        }
    }
```

1) yields:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Range.Index>' (aka 'Range') to expected argument type '[IndexPath]'

2) Which uses this method yeilds many errors as well: All are;

> Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'IndexPath'?

```
    func addTemporaryComment(cell: commentTableViewCell) {
    do {
        let url = URL(string: (arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].user.profileImageUrlString)!)
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

        cell.dateOfComment.text = arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].date
        cell.commentText.text = arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].commentText
        cell.profImage.image = image
        cell.username.text = arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].user.username
    } catch {
        print(error, ": Failed in do block converting image")
    }
}
```

}

I do not even know if either will work.

**How can I fix these if they are the right way of doing it and if not how do I make it work?**

Comment: In the `func addTemporaryComment(cell: commentTableViewCell)` you didnt pass the `indexPath` that's why it's prompt the error. Try to add indexPath param `func addTemporaryComment(cell: commentTableViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step should be to append the new data to the array used by table view to populate data

```
YourTablearray.append([labeltext])
```

Next update the table data to insert the cell at the end of the table

```
tableName.beginUpdates()
tableName.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
NSIndexPath(forRow: YourTablearray.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableName.endUpdates()
```

Comment: How do I actulay insert the cell though?

Comment: The above method insertRowsAtIndexPath creates a cell and inserts it at the index path provided. The prerequisite being that the new cell's data is updated in array

Comment: I get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (12), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Have you updated the array used to populate the tableview ? you can also try reloading the new cell inserted tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

Comment: There is no need for the calls to `begin/endUpdates` here. You only need it with multiple calls to `insert/delete/reloadRowsAt` and you need the index paths to remain consistent across those calls.

Comment: Do not use `NSIndexPath` in Swift. Use `IndexPath`. The code in this answer looks to be Swift 2 code.